# The Retry GatewayFilter do not work as expected on Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

I have a `Retry GatewayFilter` configured on my gateway for perform retries on **5xx** serial errors, however the gateway performs the retries although the service behind it return 200 OK.

```
- name: Retry
  args:
    retries: 3
    series: SERVER_ERROR
    methods: GET,POST
    backoff:
      firstBackoff: 10ms
      maxBackoff: 500ms
      factor: 2
      basedOnPreviousValue: false
```

Below the error message on gateway

```
...
DEBUG o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions - [1847f1ae] HTTP GET http://localhost:9000/resource
DEBUG o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions - [1847f1ae] Response 200 OK
DEBUG o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions - [1847f1ae] Cancel signal (to close connection)
DEBUG org.springframework.web.HttpLogging - [5451ae41-1] Resolved [IllegalStateException: The client response body has been released already due to cancellation.] for HTTP GET /service/resource
ERROR o.s.b.a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler - [5451ae41-1]  500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/service/resource"
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The client response body has been released already due to cancellation.
...
DEBUG org.springframework.web.HttpLogging - [5451ae41-1] Encoding [{timestamp=Fri Aug 21 11:49:34 ART 2020, path=/service/resource, status=500, error=Internal Server E (truncated)...]
ERROR reactor.core.publisher.Operators - Operator called default onErrorDropped java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only one connection receive subscriber allowed.
...
ERROR reactor.core.publisher.Operators - Operator called default onErrorDropped
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The client response body has been released already due to cancellation.
    at org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ReactorClientHttpResponse.lambda$getBody$0(ReactorClientHttpResponse.java:98)
...
DEBUG o.s.w.s.a.HttpWebHandlerAdapter - [5451ae41-1] Completed 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
```

I expected that gateway return **200 OK** with the response delivered by the service (I have not another response filter configured)

Today, I am using the **Hoxton.SR6** Spring Cloud release with **2.3.2.RELEASE** Spring.

**IMPORTANT:** This issue was not present in my previous configuration (**Hoxton.SR4** Spring Cloud release with **2.3.0.RELEASE** Spring)